# Coloring dynamically created table row without Javascript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, row, border, dynamic-controls

```
 Dim table1 As New HtmlTable
 Table1.Border = "1"
 Table1.BorderColor = "Blue"
        For j As Integer = 0 To 2
            Dim row As New HtmlTableRow()
            Dim cell1 As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim cell2 As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim rbl As New RadioButtonList()
            For RowIndex As Integer = 0 To 2
                rbl.ID = RowIndex
                rbl.Items.Add("Hi")
                Dim lbl1 As New Label()
                lbl1.ID = "Hi" + RowIndex.ToString
                lbl1.Text = "hello"
                lbl1.Height = "25"
                cell2.Controls.Add(lbl1)

                cell2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"))
            Next
            cell1.Controls.Add(rbl)
            row.Cells.Add(cell1)
            row.Cells.Add(cell2)
            table1.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table1)
```

In the above code the border appears for Rows and cell and to the whole table, but what i need is the border should appear for **only row** and not in the cells.

**Edit**
when added this line the row color works

```
row.Attributes.Add("style", "outline: thin solid blue;")
```

but the line diappears on double click inside the table..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `Outline` style for the Row.

You need to add it using `attributes.add()` method.

Remove border setting for the `Table1`

**See Complete code as below:**

```
Dim table1 As New HtmlTable
        'table1.Border = "1"
        'table1.BorderColor = "Blue"
        For j As Integer = 0 To 2
            Dim row As New HtmlTableRow()
            Dim cell1 As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim cell2 As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim rbl As New RadioButtonList()

            row.Attributes.Add("style", "outline: thin solid blue;")
            For RowIndex As Integer = 0 To 2
                rbl.ID = RowIndex
                rbl.Items.Add("Hi")
                Dim lbl1 As New Label()
                lbl1.ID = "Hi" + RowIndex.ToString
                lbl1.Text = "hello"
                lbl1.Height = "25"
                cell2.Controls.Add(lbl1)

                'Add This
                cell2.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
            Next
            cell1.Controls.Add(rbl)
            row.Cells.Add(cell1)
            row.Cells.Add(cell2)
            table1.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table1)
```